# Root password inside a Docker container

Tags: docker

I'm using a Docker image which was built using the USER command to use a non-root user called `dev`.
Inside a container, I'm "dev", but I want to edit the `/etc/hosts` file.

So I need to be root. I'm trying the su command, but I'm asked to enter the root password.

What's the default root user's password inside a Docker container?

Comment: just exec as a root: `docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash`. (see `H6`'s answer)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Eventually, I decided to rebuild my Docker images, so that I change the root password by something I will know.

```
RUN echo 'root:Docker!' | chpasswd
```

or

```
RUN echo 'Docker!' | passwd --stdin root
```

Comment: I tried this but it does not work on my CentOS 6 based docker. Does this command work on CentOS based docker?

Comment: Why doesn't it ask for the password twice?

Comment: can you explain what your commands do?

Comment: @CharlieParker both the commands are intended to pass a password for root user to the change password command using a pipe.  Although both the options didnt work for me while trying to gain root access to my solr docker container.

Comment: It looks like this solution is no longer valid. Tested and failed with Ubuntu 23.04 as base image. In practice my container OS default shell requires root login. At the prompt I enter root password twice from `stdin` and get thrown when I provide the correct password, i.e. the password as specified above in the corresponding image's dockerfile.

Comment: Just know that now the `Docker!` password is trivially visible for anybody with access to the container image with `docker history $image`. For a safe approach, one could use `docker build --secret` as described in [Build secrets in Docker and Compose v1, the secure way](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/build-secrets-docker-compose/).

Answer (score 870):

You can log into the Docker container using the root user (ID = 0) instead of the provided default user when you use the `-u` option. E.g.

```
docker exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash
```

> root (id = 0) is the default user within a container. The image
> developer can create additional users. Those users are accessible by
> name. When passing a numeric ID, the user does not have to exist in
> the container.

[from Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/)

**Update**: Of course you can also use the Docker management command for containers to run this:

`docker container exec -u 0 -it mycontainer bash`

Comment: It would be nice to specify that you need mycontainer up and running at the moment when you type the above commad. it works using 2 different terminals: one for mycontainer and the other for this command. Otherwise It requires that mycontainer is running as detached.

Comment: for images, use `docker run -u 0 -it mycontainer bash`

Comment: this is the answer that should be on top

Comment: @High6, when you say "You can log into the Docker Image...", I think you mean "You can log into the Docker _Container_".

Comment: Is this always possible? Or can this be blocked?

Comment: This answer should be on top!

Comment: I didn't get the "Update" part.  Ain't `docker exec` and `docker container exec` the same thing?  The rest of the params are exactly the same...

Comment: @Aidin yes, the same. Just wanted to mention the management command. Maybe they will completely replace the old ones.

Comment: This is not an option if you have to use `kubectl`.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you. This should be top.

Answer (score 69):

**There are a couple of ways to do it.**

1. To run the Docker overriding the USER setting

   ```
    docker exec -u 0 -it containerName bash
   ```

or

```
docker exec -u root -it --workdir / <containerName> bash
```

2. Make necessary file permissions, etc., during the image build in the Docker file
3. If all the packages are available in your Linux image, `chpasswd`in the dockerfile before the USER utility.

For complete reference: http://muralitechblog.com/root-password-of-a-docker-container/

Answer (score 65):

> To create/change a root password in a running container

```
docker exec -itu 0 {container} passwd
```

Comment: You save my bacon

Comment: This one should be an accepted answer!

Comment: The others are close, but this one actually has the meat.

Comment: Note: passwd is not your password. Literally, you have to type passwd, then it asks for your password.

Answer (score 28):

I am able to get it working with the below command.

```
root@gitnew:# docker exec -it --user $(username) $(containername) /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 25):

```
docker exec -u 0 -it containername bash
```

Answer (score 25):

Get a shell of your running container and change the root pass.

```
docker exec -u 0 -it <MyContainer> bash

root@MyContainer:/# passwd
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
```

Comment: How can the OP change the password when they don't know what it is?

Comment: @MEMark if you are root you are not asked about current password...

Answer (score 20):

I had exactly this problem of not being able to su to root because I was running in the container as an unprivileged user.

But I didn't want to rebuild a new image as the previous answers suggest.

Instead I have found that I could access the container as root using 'nsenter', see: https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

First determine the PID of your container on the host:

```
docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>
```

Then use nsenter to enter the container as root

```
nsenter --target <PID> --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid
```

Comment: Using boot2docker, I had to use `sudo nsenter --target <PID> --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid`

Comment: Yes, good point. You generally need root permissions to execute docker commands and I guess nsenter is the same. I didn't make this totally clear in my answer.

Comment: Since this answer was written, docker has added the command exec to do basically the same thing as nsenter, but easier and cleaner. Just a data point for those who now find this question through search. The command is "docker exec -it <containername> <command>" (command is usually /bin/bash, but you can of course do whatever you want).

Comment: Also, docker has special treatment for hosts (and resolv.conf). You should not manually edit them; docker recreates /etc/hosts on every start to reflect linked containers and the like.

Answer (score 11):

You can SSH in to docker container as root by using

```
docker exec -it --user root <container_id> /bin/bash
```

Then change root password using this

```
passwd root
```

Make sure sudo is installed check by entering

```
sudo
```

if it is not installed install it

```
apt-get install sudo
```

If you want to give sudo permissions for user **dev** you can add user dev to sudo group

```
usermod -aG sudo dev
```

Now you'll be able to run sudo level commands from your **dev** user while inside the container or else you can switch to root inside the container by using the password you set earlier.

To test it login as user **dev** and list the contents of root directory which is normally only accessible to the root user.

```
sudo ls -la /root
```

Enter password for **dev**

If your user is in the proper group and you entered the password correctly, the command that you issued with sudo should run with root privileges.

Answer (score 10):

To avoid having to rebuild your container do the following steps:

1. `docker exec -u 0 -it containerName bash`
2. `sudo visudo`
3. add the following to the end of the file:

```
your_username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

In my case I use ubuntu as my username so it would like like this:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

save the file, re-attach to your docker container, and sudo to your hearts continent.

**Bonus:** If you want to update the docker image you can then just do the following:

```
docker commit containerName NewImage
```

Answer (score 9):

The password is 'ubuntu' for the 'ubuntu' user (at least in docker for ubuntu :14.04.03).

NB: 'ubuntu' is created after the startup of the container so, if you just do this:

```
 docker run -i -t --entrypoint /bin/bash  ubuntu
```

You'll get the root prompt directly. From there you can force the password change of root, commit the container and optionally tag it (with -f) to ubuntu:latest like this:

```
root@ec384466fbbb:~# passwd
Enter new UNIX password:
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: password updated successfully
root@ec384466fbbb:~# exit

% docker commit ec3844
5d3c03e7d6d861ce519fe33b184cd477b8ad03247ffe19b2a57d3f0992d71bca

docker tag -f 5d3c ubuntu:latest
```

You must rebuild your eventual dependencies on ubuntu:latest.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest a better solution is to give the `--add-host NAME:IP` argument to docker run when starting the container. That will update the `/etc/hosts/` file without any need to become root.

Otherwise, you can override the the `USER` setting by giving the `-u USER` flag to `docker run`. I would advise against this however, as you shouldn't really be changing things in a running container. Instead, make your changes in a Dockerfile and build a new image.

Comment: I need to add entries in the hosts file while the container is running.

Comment: I also need to install new package, but I can't as I'm not root.

Comment: You can use the  `-u` flag to change user. I don't think you can do it from inside the container.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the USER root command in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3):

When you start the container, you will be root but you won't know what root's pw is. To set it to something you know simply use "passwd root". Snapshot/commit the container to save your actions.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you need to be able to do things like that under a user with `sudo` (e.g. the application running in the container provides a shell to users). Simply add this into you Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update         # If necessary
RUN apt-get install sudo   # If your base image does not contain sudo.
RUN useradd -m -N -s /bin/bash -u 1000 -p '$1$miTOHCYy$K.c4Yw.edukWJ7z9rbpTZ0' user && \
    usermod -aG sudo user  # Grant sudo to the user
USER user
```

Now under the default image user `user` you will be able to `sudo` with the password set on line 3.

See how to generate password hash for `useradd` [here](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2015/09/28/how-to-programmatically-create-system-user-with-defined-password/) or [here](https://serverfault.com/a/688380/555276).

Answer (score 3):

Some of the answers above were good, especially those like:

```
docker exec -u root -it CONTAINERID /bin/bash
```

where you get your CONTAINERID from the first column of the answer to:

```
docker ps
```

This makes you root, and you can do anything you want. But *only* if the command exists in your container. In order to do something as simple as changing the root password (as many people above have suggested), I had to turn off my VPN and do:

```
yum install -y passwd
```

While I was there, I installed vim and sudo in case I needed it in the future.

Just a note: passwd won't let you get away with easy passwords.

Answer (score 2):

try the following command to get the root access

```
$ sudo -i
```

Comment: This is unlikely to work unless you have the account in the container setup with sudo access. This would be an unusual situation and break the point of having a non-root user running the container.

Comment: Anyone know the DEFAULT su password for Docker install?
    I tried to run elevation and there IS one set.

Comment: This worked in WSL2 after exporting the docker image and importing into WSL2. From there, just do passwd to set the password for root. Exit back to non-root user and try sudo su or su. It will now work.

Answer (score 2):

By default docker containers run as the `root` user.

If you are still using the container you can use `exit` command to get back to `root` (default user) user instead of running the container again.

Example -

```
[dev@6c4c86bccf93 ~]$ ls
[dev@6c4c86bccf93 ~]$ other-commands..
[dev@6c4c86bccf93 ~]$ exit
[root@6c4c86bccf93 /]# ls
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also use it like this (if you need to confirm the password)

```
(echo 'myrootpassword'; echo 'myrootpassword') | passwd root
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two different scenarios here:

**First**

1. I created a user "rohit"
2. Now I executed su - rohit
3. Now I am currently logged-in as rohit
4. I just want to become root again.
5. **Solution**: type exit and enter

To go back to root user inside docker container from any other user.

- type exit and enter.

[image]

**Second**:

1. I created docker container without root password
2. now I need password for root
3. **Solution**: open container bash, execute passwd command and set password for root

[image]

Now I can use this password for root that I just set anywhere in the container but it won't work for ssh directly.

Answer (score -2):

Setting a fixed root password in a docker container can compromise systems, and so shouldn't be used.  Instead you might use:

```
 docker exec -itu 0 CONTAINER_ID bash
```

whenever you want root access to the container, while the container is up and running.

The above command assumes you want to run bash as your shell.
I don't use MS Windows, but I'd guess that you might try CMD or CMD.EXE instead of bash if you're on a MS Windows machine.