# How to fix mpdf temporary files directory writable issue?

Tags: laravel, mpdf

I'm getting this error in my laravel application. 
Mpdf \ MpdfException (E_ERROR)
Temporary files directory "/var/www/html/../temp/" is not writable

Please anybody tell me the solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions for that particular directory? I'm guessing that the directory needs write permissions for the HTTP server user (which in most cases is `apache` or `www-data` depending on the Linux distribution).

Comment: I'm using centOS . So here how can i give the permission

Comment: Did you try setting temprory folder path in config `'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/../../tmp',`

Comment: Additionally, did you provide permission to write `chmod 777 /var/www/protected/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/tmp`

Comment: Yes path also given, and this working perfectly in local. But in server only not working.

Answer (score 7):

I fixed it like so:

```
$mpdf = New \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir'=>storage_path('tempdir')]);
```

`storage_path('tempdir')` is the laravel-managed temporary directory.

Answer (score 5):

I solved my issue by specifying tempDir to a usable temp directory

In **config/pdf.php**

```
<?php
return [
    'mode'                  => 'utf-8',
    'format'                => 'A4',
    'author'                => '',
    'subject'               => '',
    'keywords'              => '',
    'creator'               => 'Laravel Pdf',
    'display_mode'          => 'fullpage',
    'tempDir'               => base_path('storage/app/mpdf'),
    'pdf_a'                 => false,
    'pdf_a_auto'            => false,
    'icc_profile_path'      => ''
];
```

if you are not found config/pdf.php then you should publish package's config file to your config directory by using following command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using docker, and having trouble to give the permissions make sure to enter in the docker container with root user using the follow command:

```
docker container exec -u 0 -it yourContainer bash
```

From this answer: [Root password inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721699/root-password-inside-a-docker-container)

Answer (score -1):

1. go to the directory "/var/www/html/../temp/" and check if it exists.
2. if it does not exists then create it.
3. if it exists give the necessary permission to it (usually 777 depends on your environment)

Comment: without giving permission as `777` is there any other way? `777` is bit risky i guess.

Comment: it's a temporary folder .. you can choose to give only write write access without reading but whats the point! you need your script to read and write data in this folder