# Become root in the official Oracle Database docker container

Tags: linux, docker

I [installed Oracle Database](https://developernote.com/2019/03/running-oracle-database-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-18-04/) with the official [dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.3.0/Dockerfile). The database works, but it is not clear how to became root (I need to install perl for installing [sample schemas](https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas)). I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721699/root-password-inside-a-docker-container):

```
sudo docker exec -u 0 -it oracle18se /bin/bash
```

but got:

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/home/oracle\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown
```

what does this mean?

Is there a default root password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch the working directory explicitly, e.g. with

`docker exec -u root --workdir / -ti oracle18se /bin/sh`

Some more info on that issue can be found on [github here](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/issues/1144).

Answer (score 0):

Even easier to remember:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it 19c bash
```