# Become root in a docker container

Tags: docker

I installed [Oracle Database in a Docker container](https://developernote.com/2019/03/running-oracle-database-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-18-04/), but can't figure out how to become root. If I to this from the host

```
sudo docker exec -it -u 0 oracle18se /bin/bash
```

or

```
sudo docker exec -it --user root oracle18se /bin/bash
```

I get

```
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "chdir to cwd (\"/home/oracle\") set in config.json failed: permission denied": unknown
```

If I do

```
sudo docker exec -it oracle18se /bin/bash
```

from the host, and then

```
su -
```

from the container, it asks the root password, but I do not know it.

Hy host OS is Ubuntu 18.04, [link to docker file](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/dockerfiles/18.3.0/Dockerfile)

**EDIT1:**

Found a Docker [bug](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4133).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Root password inside a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721699/root-password-inside-a-docker-container)

Comment: @banuj I get an error with this `OCI runtime exec failed...`

Answer (score 31):

#### You can exec into an existing container

`docker exec -u root -it <container-id> /bin/bash`

Output (as seen in Terminal):

`root@<container-id>:/#`

#### And to set root password use this:

Type the following command to become root user and issue passwd:

```
sudo -i
passwd
```

OR set a password for root user in a single go:

`sudo passwd root`

Test it your root password by typing the following command:

`su -`

Comment: there is the bug, see EDIT1

Comment: `docker exec -it -u root docker-container_name_1 bash` worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can connect as root in docker container using:

```
docker exec -u 0 -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```

Comment: I get `OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container...` with this command.

Answer (score 2):

The workaround is

```
sudo docker exec -u 0 -it --workdir / oracle12se /bin/bash
```