# How to temporarily allow sudo in non-root container?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, root

I'm running kubernetes container as non-root user:

```
bash-4.2$ id
uid=123456(app) gid=123456(app) groups=123456(app)
```

But inside container we need to run CLI/command which has at least one step that requires sudo permission. So how can I achieve this? Is there way to become root and sudo, execute that step, then switch back to non-root?

Comment: What is the action? In some cases you can use capabilities instead of sudo. Otherwise, sudo is the answer.

Comment: At certain step, we need sudo to fetch password/certificates to write to database. But even running sudo, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You would need to install it in the container, add a sudoers file and then you should be able to do `sudo <cmd>` as normal.

Comment: how to add sudoers? Sudo is already installed. Within the container I tried `adduser app sudo` which is not working. And `usermod -aG wheel app` but says lack of permission.

Comment: Actually I can run `sudo xxx` but it'll ask for password of app. What's the password?

Comment: @LookIntoEast : Can you refer to this [doc](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/linux/adding-users-to-sudoers) by Ninad pathak and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73293889/19230181) by Mr.B7 will help you to add sudoers.

Comment: How will you do this task on every replica of your Deployment or StatefulSet?  How will you repeat this if the cluster needs to delete a Pod, maybe because a node is being decommissioned?  (You should typically avoid running commands inside containers, especially for basic container setup, and particularly so in Kubernetes.)

Comment: You need to configure your sudoers with `NOPASSWD` for the relevant user and commands. Docs on configuration can be found here https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers

Comment: You add the sudoers file the same way you add any other file to a container image, typically using `COPY` during the docker build.

Answer (score -1):

As @Jordanm suggested and  by following this  [doc](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000016906) you can temporarily do sudo for non-root users. You can also set permissions and also passwords by following it.

> sudo (superuser do) allows you to configure non-root users to run root
> level commands without being root.  The root level administrator can
> give access through configuration of the /etc/sudoers file.  Please
> note that making changes directly to the /etc/sudoers file is
> discouraged, and that the visudo utility should be used.
>
> The syntax for using sudo is fairly simple, you specify the name of
> the command preceded by 'sudo'.  For example, if a user needed to run
> /sbin/chown, you could run it with the command:
>
> ```
> sudo /sbin/chown <user_name> <file_name>
> ```

Comment: Most images don't contain `sudo`.

Comment: @DavidMaze : But the above stack solution is a reference to this particular scenario only it's not applicable for other scenarios.